# Is a low-current electrical arc harmful to humans?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, everyday-life, biology, thermoelectricity

I've heard that electrical flux non-destructive particle testing machines are considered safe because they use less than 2 amps. I have seen an arc created between two objects do considerable damage, i.e. electrical burns.

This is a low amperage, so would an arc with less than 2 amps and roughly 10,000 volts still be harmful to humans? If not because of the electricity itself, what about from the heat?

Comment: They test these once a month and the tech that came said if it reads over 2 amps they have to take the machine out of service as to the decontrolling part can the volts usually around 9 or 10 thousand depending on what we are testing create enough heat to do damage?

Comment: We can't address questions about the safety of specific machines here. If you edit to ask about the effect of a certain amount of current or voltage on the human body, then it might be on topic.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky edit question possible to reopen?

Comment: The edit helps, but now it looks like you're asking four or five separate questions in one. Could you trim this down to ask one thing specifically?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I think I have made this an acceptable question. It is not too specific while still avoiding being too general.

Comment: OK, I guess this is reasonable. I fixed up your phrasing a little bit for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current as low as 10mA can paralyze, and 100mA can induce a heart attack. Be careful even when working with "low" currents.